# ECONNRESET when using async to scrape archive

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am currently trying to get some article data for a TensorFlow implementation I'm working on. The first source I am trying to pull against is Buzzfeed. I'm using the node.js async.js library to scrape the page, but I am having a heck of a time with always getting an ECONNRESET error from their server after about 200 or so articles.

Now when I am running this, it does seem to make requests pretty quickly, but this was why I decided to use the async.eachSeries due to the delay it applies. I'm continuing to look at this, but if anyone sees something I am doing wrong or perhaps a better way of accomplishing this, I would love to hear what you have to say. Thanks!

```
const scraper = testHelperGetScraper();

// scrape links to each news in buzz archive page
const archiveUrl = 'http://www.buzzfeed.com/archive';
let fileNum = -1;

scraper.scrapeArchiveDates(archiveUrl, function(err, dates){
    async.eachSeries(dates.yearUrl, function(url, cb){
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                scraper.scrapeArchive(url, callback);
            },
            function(urlArr, callback){
                for (var i in urlArr.url){
                    if (typeof (urlArr.url[i]) === 'string'){
                        scraper.scrapeArticle(urlArr.url[i], callback);
                    }
                }
            } ,function(res, callback){
                cb();
                callback(null, res);
            }
        ],
        function(err, buzzresult) {
            if (err){
                _logger.error('Error while inserting test data', err);
            }

            buzzresult.uniqueId = UniqueHelper.getUIntId({
                text: buzzresult.title
                , options: {
                    ignoreCase: true
                    , strip: ['urls', 'hashtags', 'users', 'quotes', 'punct']
                }
            });

            let fileFullPath = _rootFolderWhereYouWantToSave 
                + 'rawdata_' +  buzzresult.uniqueId + '.txt';
            //_logger.debug('fileFullPath', fileFullPath);

            let finalDataWritten = buzzresult.title + os.EOL + buzzresult.body + os.EOL;

            writeArticleFile(fileFullPath, finalDataWritten);
            //console.log('Finsihed calling WriteArticleFile: ', finalDataWritten);
            _counter += 1;
            console.log('NumArticlesWritten: ', _counter);
        });

    }, function (error) {
        if (error) { 
            throw error; 
        }
        console.log('Finished!');
    });
});
```

Comment: `for (var i in urlArr.url) ... scraper.scrapeArticle(urlArr.url[i], callback);` is a problem of mix async and sync code. Change `for` to `async.each(urlArr, scraper.scrapeArticle, callback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplify your code a little.
You can use named function to create a more readable code.

```
const scraper = testHelperGetScraper();
const archiveUrl = 'http://www.buzzfeed.com/archive';
let fileNum = -1;

scraper.scrapeArchiveDates(archiveUrl, function(err, dates){
    async.eachSeries(dates, parseDate, (err) => (err) ? throw err : console.log('Finished!'););
});

function parseDate(date, callback) {
    scraper.scrapeArchive(date.yearUrl, function(err, urls) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err);

        urls = urls.filter((url) => typeof(url) === 'string'));
        async.each(urls, scraper.scrapeArticle, function(err, buzzresult) {
            if (err) {
                _logger.error('Error while inserting test data', err);
                return callback(err);
            }

            ... // process result
        })  
    });
}
```

Comment: Aikon I truly can't thank you enough! It makes me a bit sick in that your code not only looks so elegant but that it worked as expected.  I clearly still have so much to learn :)  That said, this is perfect. I realized that on buzzfeed that they have a calendar for each day as well so i am going to go about implementing that now as well, but this solved all my issues.  Thanks again!!

Comment: One last comment to make on this just in case anyone runs into this as well.  The one slight change I needed to make was using async.map instead of async.each primarily due to the fact that I needed to handle buzzresult. After making the change, all worked as expected. I have changed the above logic to show the same.